# Existence of an unbounded positive sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $f'(x_{n})<f(ax_{n}), \forall n\in \Bbb N^+$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $a>1$ and let $f:(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow (0,+\infty)$ be differentiable.
Show that there exists a positive  sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=+\infty$, such that
$$f'(x_{n})<f(ax_{n}),\ \forall n\in \Bbb N^{+}.$$

My try: I note that 
$$(f(x)e^{-x})'=f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}=e^{-x}[f'(x)-f(x)],$$

but I can't move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reduction to absurdity, suppose that the conclusion is false, i.e. there exists $b>0$, such that 
$$f'(x)\ge f(ax),\quad\forall x\ge b.$$
Since $f>0$, it follows that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[b,+\infty)$, so by mean value theorem, for every $x\ge b$, there exists $\xi\in(x, ax)$, such that
$$f(ax)>f(ax)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(ax-x)\ge f(a\xi)(ax-x)> f(ax)(ax-x).$$
However, the inequality above cannot hold when $x\ge \frac{1}{a-1}$, which completes the proof.